How to change Toolbar icon size?
I go to System Settings > Icons > Configure Icon Sizes:

But am unable to change the 22
What do I do?
Some output from neofetch
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
Resolution: 1920x1080, 3840x2160
DE: Plasma 5.24.7
WM: KWin
Edit: I see now that the control to adjust the size is disabled.
